# Perl plugins don't work on my rxvt-unicode!

Tags: perl, urxvt, x-resources

I wanted to add some features to my urxvt so I changed my `.Xresources` file. for the global effect of plugins I copied them all to `/usr/lib/urxvt/perl`. but still no multi tab, clickable link or changing the font size on the fly. The keymap hassle is active too.

```
Urxvt.perl-lib: /usr/lib/urxvt/perl/
Urxvt.iso14755: false
Urxvt.iso14755_52: false
Urxvt.perl-ext-common: default,url-select,tabbedex,matcher,keyboard-select,font-size
Urxvt.keysym.M-u: perl:url-select:select_next
Urxvt.keysym.M-Escape: perl:keyboard-select:activate
Urxvt.keysym.M-s: perl:keyboard-select:search
Urxvt.url-select.launcher: /usr/bin/xdg-open
Urxvt.url-select.underline: true
Urxvt.matcher.button: 1
Urxvt.keysym.C-Delete: perl:matcher:last
Urxvt.keysym.M-Delete: perl:matcher:list
Urxvt.colorUL: #a0db8e
Urxvt.tabbed.new-button: false
Urxvt.keysym.Control-t: perl:tabbedex:new_tab
Urxvt.keysym.Control-Tab: per:tabbedex:next_tab
Urxvt.keysym.Control-Shift-Tab: perl:tabbedex:prev_tab
Urxvt.keysym.Control-Shoft-Left: perl:tabbedex:move_tab_left
Urxvt.keysym.Control-Shift-Right: perl:tabbedex:move_tab_right
Urxvt.keysym.Control-Shift-R: perl:tabbedex:rename_tab
 URxvt.keysym.C-Up:     perl:font-size:increase
 URxvt.keysym.C-Down:   perl:font-size:decrease
 URxvt.keysym.C-S-Up:   perl:font-size:incglobal
 URxvt.keysym.C-S-Down: perl:font-size:decglobal
```

-.-.-.-.-.

The contents of `/usr/lib/urxvt/perl`:

```
total 224
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2137 Oct 14 02:30 xim-onthespot
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2956 Oct 14 02:30 urxvt-popup
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 9366 Oct 14 23:41 url-select
-rwxr-xr-x 1 r004 users 17902 Oct 14 23:44 tabbedex
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 9486 Oct 14 02:30 tabbed
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 531 Oct 14 02:30 selection-to-clipboard
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3968 Oct 14 02:30 selection-popup
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3303 Oct 14 02:30 selection-pastebin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2627 Oct 14 02:30 selection-autotransform
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5324 Oct 14 02:30 selection
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5283 Oct 14 02:30 searchable-scrollback
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3747 Oct 14 02:30 remote-clipboard
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2069 Oct 14 02:30 readline
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1664 Oct 14 02:30 overlay-osc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2172 Oct 14 02:30 option-popup
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 9226 Oct 14 02:30 matcher
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2892 Oct 14 02:30 macosx-clipboard-native
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2016 Oct 14 02:30 macosx-clipboard
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2023 Oct 14 02:30 kuake
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 781 Oct 14 02:30 keysym-list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 14681 Oct 14 23:41 keyboard-select
-rwxr-xr-x 1 r004 users 12161 Oct 14 23:42 font-size
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1274 Oct 14 02:30 example-refresh-hooks
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 648 Oct 14 02:30 digital-clock
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1134 Oct 14 02:30 confirm-paste
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 493 Oct 14 02:30 clipboard-osc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1644 Oct 14 02:30 block-graphics-to-ascii
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1403 Oct 14 02:30 bell-command
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 33568 Oct 14 02:30 background
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Oct 14 02:30 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct 14 23:45 .
```

Comment: It is my current urxvt information.  https://gist.github.com/d0b91f8760eb85498a0b

Comment: I assume you edited `~/.Xresources` and not `~/.Xreourse` (please correct that typo if so). What is the directory whose contents you're showing us?

Comment: In addition, the top of your code paste says you're using `/usr/lib/urxt/perl/` rather than `/usr/lib/urxvt/perl/`. Is that typo in your actual file?

Comment: @HalosGhost I edited the post several times. so it is a typo basically.

Comment: I only asked because if that typo exists in the original file, then that might explain your issue.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was from `Urxvt.*` .
I changed it to the `URxvt.*` and It works now.
I also put `matcher` after `default`. (but I down't think it had any thing to do with the problem.)